# Some doubts about libraries

Tags: c++, linux, libraries

Say, I want to write a program in C++ in Linux and I need some specific libraries. There are 2 ways of getting these libraries:

1. Using the command line--> apt-get install library
2. Downloading and extracting a .zip or .tar file from their website.

Now my questions are:

For the first method I have seen libraries being downloaded with apt-get install library and apt-get install library-dev. I know dev means development or developer, but what is the difference between installing the dev and not installing the dev? What does dev do, exactly?

For the second method, do I need to build the libraries using a compiler? Because I have seen tutorials doing it but the OS used was usually Windows, do I only have to build them on Windows and not Linux?

Also, say I can only use the 2nd method for a certain library and not the first one. After extracting, what am I supposed to do? Is there any default way of installing a library manually or is each library different?

Finally, when I use the first method where is the library installed to? Is it /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib or /usr/include? Because when I have to link to these libraries in the Linker's settings I only write their name, not the path so I assume there is already a default path for libraries to be in.

One last question: Is there any default way of installing and using libraries in general or does that depend on what I want to do, programming language, etc...?

Comment: Do you want to *build* with the library? Then you need the development package. The development package usually contains *header files* and static libraries.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't know whether or not if I want to build the library. That's what I am trying to figure out. When do I need to build a library? Why is it necessary to build it? I am not very experienced.

Comment: Not build the library, build ***with*** the library. Like I said, the development package `libsomename-dev` usually contains the header files needed to use the library from your own source.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, if I want to write a program that uses functions, constants, etc... from this library that's when I need the dev? Ok, I understand. What about the non-development package? What does that one contain?

Comment: That contains the actual (non-static) library and other run-time support files that the library might need. The non-development package is needed by everyone who want to run a program linking with the library.

Answer (score 1):

The second method is very broad because it depends entirely on the how the project is designed including the build system used etc. Things get a little more conformant when you use a distribution's managed packages.

If you want to develop a program that uses the library you need the `library-dev` package that usually contains the `C/C++/etc..` header files.

Many development package conform to a standard tool that helps your build system find the libraries header and binary files.

For example `libcurl` uses the `pkg-config` system so its compiler components can be found from the command line like this:

```
pkg-config libcurl --libs # print the library link flags
```

You can then add that to your `Makefile` (or whatever build system you use):

```
program:
     g++ -o program program.cpp $(shell pkg-config libcurl --libs)
```

The `$(shell pkg-config libcurl --libs)` part adds the correct compiler flags to link with the library.

Not all dev packaged use `pkg-config`. Some come with their own tools (like `mysql_config`) while others let you guess and try to figure it all out for yourself (looking at you `libclang`).